# Print ASCII lines next to each other in Java?

Tags: java

I don't know if this is ASCII per se, but I couldn't really think of a better term.

So I have a string for each letter of the alphabet as a stylized version of it.

```
String asciiA = """
       █████████ \r
      ███░░░░░███\r
     ░███    ░███\r
     ░███████████\r
     ░███░░░░░███\r
     ░███    ░███\r
     █████   █████\r
    ░░░░░   ░░░░░\r
                 \r
                 \r
                 \r""";
String asciiB = """
     ███████████\r
    ░░███░░░░░███\r
     ░███    ░███\r
     ░██████████\r
     ░███░░░░░███\r
     ░███    ░███\r
     ███████████\r
    ░░░░░░░░░░░ \r
                \r
                \r
                \r""";
```

Like this.

I made it so that when player presses, say, AB, the stylized version of those letters are displayed on screen. But the problem is they are not displayed on the same line even though I use `System.out.print();` and \r for the characters. I'm thinking it's because these are special characters. Does anyone know of a way?

Comment: Split the strings on `\r`. This will give you an array of strings for each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you want to write your stylized version of AB you need to print the "first line" of A followed by the "first line" of B, then seconds, etc.

So the best would be to have (as @johnny suggested) an array of "lines" for your characters. Like:

```
String []asciiB = {
    " ███████████ ",
    "░░███░░░░░███", 
    ...
};
```

and then if you want to print `AB` to iterate over both arrays line by line in parallel:

```
for (int i=0; i<asciiA.length; i++)
    System.out.println(asciiA[i]+" "+asciiB[i]);
```

Generalized it with a map from character-to-print to array-of-lines:

```
Map<Character,String[]> ascii = new HashMap<>();
ascii.put('A',asciiA);
...

String s = "ABCD";
for (int i=0; i<numberOfLinesPerChar; i++)
    for (char c: s) {
        System.out.print(ascii.get(c)[i]);
        System.out.print(' '); // separator
    }
    System.out.println(); // end of line
}
```