# Printing a word using Star Pattern in Java, but coming in vertical way, expected horizontally

Tags: java, for-loop

I wanted to print "TEL" using star patterns and for loop.

But when I tried it, I'm not getting it in a horizontal way, instead in a vertical way.

The output:

```
*****
  *  
  *  
  *  
  *  



******
*
****
*
******
```

**CODE**

````
The code :
```java
public class test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int h = 5;
            int w = (2*h)-1;

            int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < h; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    System.out.print("*");
                else if (j == h / 2)
                    System.out.print("*");
                else if (i == h)
                {
                    System.out.println("     ");
                }
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
            
        

        }

         System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        for (i = 0; i < h; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            for (j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {
                if ((i == 0 || i == h - 1)
                    || (i == h / 2
                        && j <= h / 2))
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    continue;
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        for (i = 0; i < h; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            for (j = 0; j <= h; j++)
            {
                if (i == h - 1)
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();       
            }
        }

    }
````

The thing is that, I want "TE" in a star way and in a horizontal way.
I've tried multiple times, but I've got no good.

But I wanted TE in this, not like

```
T
E
```

Can anybody suggest what can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: You will need to print the first row of each letter *before* you print a newline.

Comment: Oh Okay. ll try it.

Comment: @tgdavies can you send me the code to print TEL in a horizontal manner if you can???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print ASCII lines next to each other in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69346613/print-ascii-lines-next-to-each-other-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

you should write `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`

Comment: Wouldn't that just get all the lines of the first letter concatenated into the first line of output? Surely not what OP wants. I suspect you did not try your proposal. Please show the code and desribe how you tested it.